# How to allow Users to add image for their profile

Tags: image, upload

I am wondering what is the usual way of allowing users to add a profile picture  to their profile on my website .
I am creating a social network type website, where users can register and maintain their profile. Like we know users can upload a profile image for their profile,which should be part of the database along with their profile info. but how is this usually done on the frontend using html5/jquery+ajax+php .

Comment: you should edit your question and define a language, framework, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You question is very vague. Assuming:

You are talking about a WebBased system; You have a database system with users;

Create a form to allow a user to upload a file, save that file in a specific place, naming it something unique. Save the unique name to a field in the users profile. Every time you load that profile, use the unique name of the file to set it as the profile picture.

Please refine your question to include a language, and more specifics.

**EDIT**

Like stated, create a form that will allow a user to upload a picture:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
</form>
```

In a php scrip, take the file that you uploaded and move it to a permanent storage location with a unique name:

```
<?php
    $pathToImage = "/new/file/path/unique/345908.png";
    move_uploaded_files($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $pathToImage);
?>
```

Use SQL to change the unique name in your users profile

```
<?php
    mysql_query('UPDATE users SET profile_image = ".$pathToImage." WHERE username="matt"');
?>
```

Comment: Sorry about that! I am creating a social network type website, where users can register and maintain their profile. Like we know users can upload a profile image for their profile,which should be part of the database along with their profile info. but how is this usually done on the frontend.

Comment: Please add this information to your original question (there's an "edit" link under it). Also add some information about the technology you are using, since the solution will be different for each technology.